# Can i have data tables in the examples of cucumber?

Tags: testing, cucumber, ui-automation, cucumber-java

I am looking for something like below . Let me know if we have a way to do it .

```
Scenario Outline : Verify

Examples :
| name  | rollno |  marks                         |
| raj   | 110    | |science | maths | test      | |
                   | 95     | 20    | finaltest |
                   | 100    | 20    | midterm   |
```

Answer (score 1):

Nested data tables are not supported in examples.

Why not move the science, maths marks up a level instead?

Or you could use a delimited string of all the subject and marks in one column - Science$95@Maths$20... Split this in your step definition to create your objects etc.

Or one column with a delimited string of subjects and another a delimited string with marks of the respective subjects. Makes things clearer than one string but you will need the splitting logic twice.

Comment: because i have a scenario where for each student i should create multiple records of marks and it varies with student.If i move it one level up it will create two records with name raj and marks as different.

Comment: In the edited question you have added the test criterion, so even if you move the marks for each subject and the test name to the top level, the combination of name(or roll no) and test name will be unique...